# How to choose the numbers which are lowest 10% in the list?

Tags: python, min

I would like to get the lowest 10% numbers in the list.

```
List = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
```

From the above list, I expect to get the result. 
    result = [1,2] 
which is the lowest 10% on the list.

Comment: sort and get arr[: len(arr) // 10] ?

Comment: are elements unique? what if input is `[1]*10`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If every elements are unique, you can simply sort and slice the data

```py
l = list(range(1, 21))

number_value_to_get = len(l)//10
print(sorted(l)[:number_value_to_get]
```

However, in most of the case, this is wrong, you can use the numpy version

```
import numpy as np

l = np.array(range(1, 21))
threshold = np.percentile(l, 10) # calculate the 10th percentile
print(l[l < threshold]) # Filter the list.
```

Be aware to need to define if it this is 10% inclusive or not

```
import numpy as np

l = np.array([1]*20)
threshold = np.percentile(l, 10)
print(l[l < np.percentile(l, 10)]) # Gives you empty list
print(l[l <= np.percentile(l, 10)]) # Gives you full list
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use numpy there is a built in percentile function:

```
import numpy

l = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20])

print(l[l < numpy.percentile(l,10)])
```

Answer (score 2):

`result = List[:int(len(List)*0.1)]`

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
sorted(lis)[:int((0.1 * len(lis)))]
```

where `lis` is your list.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go
=^..^=

```
import numpy as np

List = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]

percent = 10
values = list(sorted(np.asarray(List, dtype=np.int))[:int(len(List)/(100/percent))])
```

Output:

```
[1, 2]
```

Comment: Oh, what I'm expecting is [1,2]. The real element, not the index.

Answer (score 1):

```
 # list of values
lstValues = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]

# get maximum value out of list values
max = max(lstValues)

# calculate 10 percent out of max value
max /= 10

# print all the elements which are under the 10% mark
print([i for i in lstValues if i <= max])
```

Comment: You should be careful while overloading the built in methods

Comment: What do you mean with overloading the methods?

Comment: After that, you cannot use `max(1, 2)` anymore. My wording might be wrong

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. Thx a lot!

Comment: My pleasure ! :)

Comment: that solution will only work if all of the elements of the list are not random or do not follow a compatible pattern. lstValues = [1, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9] will not work at all for exemple.

Comment: @MatthieuRaynauddeFitte it depends on the need, the question was not very clear, maybe OP wanted "take the elements < max(list)/10", and this solution would work.

Comment: @BlueSheepToken true, the question does need a bit of clarification

Comment: @MatthieuRaynauddeFitte my bad, I didn't think about different possible patterns.

Answer (score 1):

```
mylist=[int(x) for x in range(1,21)]
mylist.sort()
newlist=[]
for i in range(len(mylist)//10): #just index through the 10% elements with this
    newlist.append(mylist[i])
print(newlist)
```